# javascript, timeout, button, movement.

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've only been working with javascript for the past 3 days and I have an assignment to do. (Don't ask me why they're making me create a game on my first js assignment) I've made this game you can view it here http://nwdevelopment.host56.com/game.html

How it should work: Click the start button, then the start button goes away and the animation starts on the character. Timer will still go until 30 seconds are up. (1 second currently for testing purposes) Game ends and displays amounts of clicks in pop up ( + 50 to win). Start button comes back up and you can play again.

The problem i'm having is:

1: I need to make the button go away when clicked, but still continue to count down until the end of the game but come back up when the game ends. Where can I learn to do this? Direct me to a site or show me please.

2: During all of this, when you press start game, i need Ganon to move around slowly while you click on him and the score goes up. I got the score to go up but I can't get him to move and I'm not even sure where to start. Also, when you click on him I need it to move 10 pixels randomly on the screen.

I need this in the simplest form you can give me with javascript. Can you point me in the right direction for tutorials or something? Here is the code so far, sorry the CSS and scripts are in one file currently. (leaving out the CSS as i don't think you need it.)

```
    <div id="textWrapper">
<h1>Try to Defeat<br /> Ganon!</h1>
<p class="description">Click on Ganon and watch your score rise! If you hit     Ganon enough times before the time runs out, you win!</p>
<ul>
    <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="unit3a.html">UNIT3A</a></li>
    <li><a href="unit3b.html">UNIT3B</a></li>
    <li><a href="game.html">Game</a></li>
</ul>
<br />
<!-- Counter -->
<div id="numberCounter">
<p>0</p>
</div>
</div>


<div id="backgroundImageWrapper">
<div id="ganonWrapper">
<img src="ganon.png" alt="ganon" onclick="myFunction()"/>
</div>

<div id="buttonWrapper">
<button id="button" onclick="myTimer()">Start Game</button>
</div>
</div>

<!-- START JAVASCRIPT -->
<script>
var counter = 0;

function add() {
return counter += 1;
}

function myFunction(){
document.getElementById("numberCounter").innerHTML = add();
}
function myTimer() {
setTimeout(function(){ alert("Game over!"); }, 1000);
}


</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this little fiddle can help you get the timer things to work.

http://jsfiddle.net/2zfdLf0q/2/

```
// lets put everything in our game object
var game = {

    //this is the init function (we call this function on page load (see last line))
    init: function(){
        //we attach a click event on the button
        document.getElementById('start').addEventListener('click', function(){
            //we hide the button
            document.getElementById('start').style.display = "none";
            //on click we start the timer
            game.timer.start();
        });
    },

    //this is the timer object
    timer: {
        startTime: 5,   //the time we start with (used to reset)
        currentTime: 5, //the counter used to remember where the counter is
        interval: null, //the interval object is stored here so we can stop it later
        start: function(){

            //when we start the timer we set an interval to execute every 1000 miliseconds
            game.timer.interval = setInterval(function(){
                game.timer.currentTime -= 1;  //we minus 1 every second to the timer current time

                //update the textbox to show the user what the time is
                document.getElementById('counter').value = game.timer.currentTime + ' seconds'; 

                //if timer hits 0 we show the game is over and reset the game, we also clear the timer
                //so it wouldn't count below zero
                if(game.timer.currentTime == 0){
                    alert('game over'); 
                    game.reset();
                    clearTimeout(game.timer.interval);
                }

            },1000);
        }

    },

    //this is the reset function
    reset: function(){
        document.getElementById('start').style.display = 'inline-block';
        game.timer.currentTime =  game.timer.startTime; 
        document.getElementById('counter').value = game.timer.currentTime + ' seconds';
    }

}

//we start the game on page load
//you should wrap this in
//window.onload = function(){}
//but jsFiddle does this automaticly
game.init();
```

Comment: This helped me in 1 aspect i got the start button functioning correctly. But can't for the life of me animate the character. -_-